# R package build failing on Unix machines due to missing GSL - GNU Scientific Library

Tags: r, travis-ci, gsl, r-package

I am facing a particularly vexing problem with `R` package development. My own package, called `ggstatsplot` (https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot), depends on `userfriendlyscience`, which depends on another package called `MBESS`, which itself ultimately depends on another package called `gsl`. There is no problem at all for installation of `ggstatsplot` on a **Windows** machine (as assessed by `AppVeyor` continuous integration platform: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot).

But whenever the package is to be installed on **Unix** machines, it throws the error that `ggstatsplot` can't be downloaded because `userfriendlyscience` and `MBESS` can't be downloaded because `gsl` can't be downloaded. The same thing is also revealed on `Travis` continuous integration platform with virtual Unix machines, where the package build fails (https://travis-ci.org/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot).

Now one way to solve this problem for the user on the Unix machine is to configure GSL (as described here:
[installing R gsl package on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781125/installing-r-gsl-package-on-mac)), but I can't possibly expect every user of `ggstatsplot` to go through the arduous process of configuring `GSL`. I want them to just run `install.packages("ggstatsplot")` and be done with it.

So I would really appreciate if anyone can offer me any helpful advice as to how I can make my package user's life simpler by removing this problem at its source. Is there something I should include in the package itself that will take care of this on behalf of the user?

Comment: I don't think the situation is as bad as you make it out to be. The R `gsl` package is available in binary form for Mac, so that leaves Linux. GSL is packaged for most Linux distros, e.g., as `libgsl-dev` and `libgsl2` on Ubuntu. So, Mac and Windows users do `install.packages("ggstatsplot")` and Linux users do `apt-get install libgsl-dev libgsl2` followed by `install.packages("ggstatsplot")`. It all seems pretty typical to me.

Comment: @Ista Thanks for your input and glad to hear that it's not as big of an issue as I think it is. I personally don't work with either Mac or Linux, so this is based purely on CI platforms I'm using to check package build and am confused by the error on Mac but not on Windows.
For example, doing `install.packages("ggstatsplot")` works with Windows, but **not** with Mac and I'm not sure why that's the case. In other words, why do Windows users not face the same problems as Mac and Ubuntu users. I've asked my colleagues with Macs to install my package and it fails every time, but never on Windows.

Comment: I don't have access to a Mac at the moment, but I'll check when I do. My assumption is that Windows users don't have problems because the R package is already built for them by CRAN. This applies to Mac users as well, so I would expect it to work there also. I'll check that when I can.

Comment: I checked on a Mac and `gsl` installs and works just fine. No installation of GSL is required.

Comment: @Ista Thanks for checking. Yes, that's because I pushed some new changes last night based on the answer posted below. Now the package installation works just fine with `osx`, but still has issues with `Linux` (https://travis-ci.org/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot). Working on resolving that now.

Comment: No, this is not because of any change you made; my point is that the `gsl` R package installs fine on Mac. There also is nothing to resolve for Linux users; they just need to install system dependencies as usual, e.g., `libgsl-dev` in this case. *You* may wish to resolve travis-ci issues -- see https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r#APT-packages for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may not have a satisfying solution via changes to your R package (I'm not sure either way).  If the gsl package authors (which include a former R Core member) didn't configure it to avoid a pre-req installation of a linux package, there's probably a good reason not to.

But it may be some consolation that most R+Linux users understand that some R packages first require installing the underlying Linux libraries (*eg*, through [apt](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) or [dnf](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF?rd=Dnf)/[yum](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Yum)).

#### Primary Issue: making it easy for the users to install

Try to be super clear on the GitHub readme and the CRAN [INSTALL file](https://github.com/cran/gsl/blob/master/INSTALL).  The gsl package has [decent CRAN directions](https://github.com/cran/gsl/blob/master/INSTALL).  This leads to the following bash code:

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
```

The best example of clear (linux pre-req package) documentation I've seen is from the `curl` and `sf` packages.  `sf`'s [CRAN page](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=sf) lists only the human names of the 3 libraries, but the [GitHub page](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf#ubuntu) provides the exact bash commands for three major distribution branches.  The curl package does this very well too (eg, [CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=curl) and [GitHub](https://github.com/jeroen/curl#installation)).  For example, it provides the following explanation and bash code:

> Installation from source on Linux requires [`libcurl`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). On **Debian** or **Ubuntu** use [libcurl4-openssl-dev](https://packages.debian.org/testing/libcurl4-openssl-dev):

```
sudo apt-get install -y libcurl-dev
```

Ideally your documentation would describe how do install the gsl linux package on multiple distributions.

Disclaimer: I've never developed a package that directly requires a Linux package, but I use them a lot.  In case more examples would help, [this doc](https://github.com/OuhscBbmc/RedcapExamplesAndPatterns/blob/master/DocumentationGlobal/ResourcesInstallation.md#installation-optional) includes a script I use to install stuff on new Ubuntu machines.  Some commands were stated explicitly in the package documentation; some had little or no documentation, and required research.

**edit 2018-04-07**:
I encountered my new favorite example: the [sys package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=sys) uses a [config](https://github.com/jeroen/sys/blob/d3767c3e06a65821f415e4d66ae2675584bed86e/configure#L39-L48) file to produce the following message in the R console.  While installing 100+ packages on a new computer, it was nice to see this direct message, and not have to track down the R package and the documentation about its dependencies.

> On Debian/Ubuntu this package requires AppArmor.
>
> Please run: sudo apt-get install libapparmor-dev

Another good one is [pdftools](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=pdftools), that also uses a [config](https://github.com/ropensci/pdftools/blob/f88dc881d6d6c7b83a20c7b1de7d7ce52f4efbc3/configure#L57-L74) file (and is also developed by [Jeroen Ooms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318752)).

#### Secondary Issue: installing on Travis

The [userfriendly travis config file](https://github.com/Matherion/userfriendlyscience/blob/07506c966a0acdbe4b4a42bc91948a7cf050dec2/.travis.yml) apparently installs a lot of binaries directly (including [gsl](https://github.com/Matherion/userfriendlyscience/blob/07506c966a0acdbe4b4a42bc91948a7cf050dec2/.travis.yml#L97)), unlike the [current ggstatsplot version](https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/blob/8a50552e5f50181f4074c52cbd11ce755db9b992/.travis.yml).

Alternatively, I'm more familiar with telling travis to install the linux package, as demonstrated by [curl's config file](https://github.com/jeroen/curl/blob/85d22ebf3996b0670a990b9f8d866e39501e88a4/.travis.yml#L28-L30).  As a bonus, this probably more closely replicates what typical users do on their own machines.

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

**Follow up 2018-03-13** Indrajeet and I tweaked the travis file so it's working.  [Two sections were changed](https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/pull/23/files) in the yaml file:

1. The `libgsl0-dev` entry was added under the `packages` section (similar to the libcurl4-openssl-dev entry above).
2. Packages were listed in the [`r_binary_packages`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/#Additional-Dependency-Fields) section so they install as binaries.  The build was timing out after 50 minutes, and now it's under 10 min.  In this particular package, the `r_binary_packages` section was nested in the Linux part of the Travis matrix so it wouldn't interfere with his two OS X jobs on Travis.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer and also for links to extensive documentation! The `curl` package's `travis.yml` file was especially useful. The installation now works for `osx`, but the build is still failing for `linux` machines (https://travis-ci.org/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot). Trying to figure out how to resolve that now.

Comment: I think the `linux` build is working now, but it's still not succeeding (https://travis-ci.org/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/jobs/351456750) because of the following error - `The job exceeded the maximum time limit for jobs, and has been terminated.` Any ideas about how to get around that?

Comment: These instructions did something but did not result in an installation of GSL that could be found by the r package `gsl`. When I follow the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583193/installing-r-gsl-package-on-ubuntu all went well and GSL appeared in a location where gsl could find it.